# Set Text in Textbox and Get New Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, textbox, ckeditor

I am setting the text of a textbox in C# like this:

```
string content = rdr["content"].toString(); 
tbContent.Text = content;
```

I want the user to be able to edit the text in the textbox if there are formatting and grammatical errors from the current text. This is doable, but when I get the text from the textbox like below, the edits are not there and the original text is in turn collected.

```
string newContent = tbContent.Text;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The important here is, Disabled the character that you don't want to be entered by the user. On Keypressed event.

Comment: Your code snippet looks fine. Where are you collecting the `newContent`? Are you sure it's being done *after* some changes are made?

Comment: Check which events you are doing this? PageLoad? Using IsPostBack?

Comment: newContent is collecting on a button click event, it should get the edits as they are changed in the textbox and the page is reloaded after being pushed to the database

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code return to this:

```
string content = rdr["content"].toString(); 
tbContent.Text = content;
```

thats is why it returns to original text..

Try to use `IsPostBack` or `!IsPostBack`

try to run a debug maybe it turn back to your `rdr["content"].toString();` before `string newContent = tbContent.Text;`

Comment: The first snippet occurs on a PageLoad function, thus shouldn't be the problem